# Levar dado da linha atual, para linha anterior, se o teste logico for verdadeiro

Tags: python, pandas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso levar os dados da coluna **Histórico**, para a coluna ***Descrição***, porém de maneira que os dados fiquem alinhados com as informações, já preenchidas nas outras colunas.

Por exemplo, conforme a imagem do dataframe:

"Despesas Bancarias" da linha 16 (Coluna Histórico) fique alinhada com as informações da linha 14 (Coluna Descrição)

**Tentei usar o código abaixo, mas não deu certo:**

```
Descricao = []
for i in rzBase.itertuples():
  Descricao.append( i.Histórico if i.Lançamento == 'Complemento:' else complemento)
  complemento = rzBase.fillna(method='ffill')
rzBase['Descrição'] = Descricao
```

Ele leva tudo que o `itertuples` mapeia na linha, mas não é bem isso que eu preciso. Preciso que leve o dado da linha atual, para linha anterior, se o teste logico for verdadeiro...

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas funções do Pandas: shift e index. Elas devem ajudar. Exemplo: `df.loc[df["valor"] >= 3000].index` Depois basta diminuir um de cada item da lista e atribuir o valor à coluna. Talvez tenha modo mais fácil.

Answer (score -3):

Olá , fiz um exemplo de como iterar coluna por coluna, e linha a linha, e caso a coluna 3 NÃO estiver vazia ele substitui na linha anterior da coluna dois o valor da coluna 3.

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['C1L0', 'C1L1', 'C1L2'], 'Column2': ['C2L0', 'C2L1', 'C2L2'], 'Column3':[' ','C3L2 ',' ']})
number_lines, number_columns = df.shape##Get total lines and colums as int value

condition = ' '

for column in range(number_columns-1):##Column by column except the Column3
    for line in range((number_lines)):##Line by line 
        previous_line = line - 1
        if df.loc[line,'Column3'] != ' ':
            df.loc[previous_line,'Column2'] = df.loc[line,'Column3']

print(df)
```

Resultado:

```
 Column1 Column2 Column3
0    C1L0   C3L2
1    C1L1    C2L1   C3L2
2    C1L2    C2L2
```